# php image resizing but not saving after resizing

Tags: php

i am trying to upload image and then resizing the image and save it. the upload is working fine and the resizing is also working but the resized image is not saving. if i use header ("Content-type: image/jpeg"); then it showing the resized image also. but after resizing the image is not getting saved.
here is my code:

```
    $filename = $_FILES['myfile']['name'][$count] ;

    $filename = uploadfilename($filename);  
    $filename1=$iiid."blog".$filename;
    $target_path = "../photo/";

    $target_path = $target_path . repc($filename1);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$count], $target_path);    
    $dbfield = $count+1;           
    $sql="update product set img_".$dbfield." ='".rep($filename1)."' where id='".$iiid."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count++;
    // header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    // print_r(get_resource_type($uploadedImage));exit();
    // $resizedImage = PIPHP_ImageResize($target_path,400,400);
    $w = 100;
    $h = 100;
    list($width, $height) = @getimagesize($target_path);  
    $source = @ImageCreateFromJPEG($target_path);
    $resized_img = @ImageCreateTrueColor($w, $h);       
    @ImageCopyResampled($resized_img, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $width, $height);
    @ImageJPEG($resized_img);
```

Comment: you haven't sent a second parameter on `ImageJPEG()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php "_The path or an open stream resource (which is automatically being closed after this function returns) to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly._" Also please don't go too crazy with `@` when developing PHP.

Comment: thanx! just used the second parameter. but i am getting a black image.

Comment: Remove all the `@` prefix, Then review that your `ImageCopyResampled` is working.

Comment: thanx man...now it's working fine...